# From where can I download JBPM Runtime?

Tags: runtime, jbpm, bpmn

I am new to JBPM.
I downloaded and started using eclipse. I then installed the JBPM plugin and modeler 2.0 plugin.
When I create a new JBPM project, it asks for JBPM runtime.
I searched a lot on the internet but the runtime is not available as independent package. Please provide me with some direct independent link.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jBPM Runtime is located inside the jBPM library.

To add it to Eclipse, in the window to add a jBPM Runtime, just travel to the place where you've putted the library and select it (the library folder). Eclipse will automatically identify the jBPM Runtime.

To download the jBPM Library, go here:
https://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html

and download the `jBPM 6.5.0.Final-bin.zip` file.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I never used the eclipse plugin myself, I think that what you are looking for is the kie-workbench (aka Drools Workbench): http://www.drools.org/download/download.html

You can get more information in jbpm's and drools' documentation:

- http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMOverview.html#d0e292
- http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Beta1/drools-docs/html/pt05.html

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

It is a "runtime" folder in the jbpm installer.

First, download a jbpm installer zip...
http://jbpm.org/download/download.html

Unzip the installer, then you can find the "runtime" directory.

Cut and paste the path to be the jbpm runtime in your eclipse.